# 1 field: Autosuggest + Search

Tags: search, solr, typo3, autosuggest

I've the following usecase: 
I want to use a field for autosuggest and for fulltext-search with "q"-parameter
Now the problem is: When I want to do full-textsearch and choose "*_textS" or "*_textM" as type, then fulltextsearch works perfectly word-based. 
But because of the tokenization which takes place for "*_textM" in solr, I get only 1 lowercase-piece of the whole word when doing autosuggest with "Eid/Suggest".
For example if I have indexed "This is a value" as "_textS" I only get "this" for autosuggest. What I need as autosuggest-value is "This is a value".

What's the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use same field for autosuggest as well as search. Then you can create a **copy field** of that field with different fieldType. For example **content** is the field which is you want to use for autosuggest-search.
Then you can use **content** as full text-search and create an another field **content_suggest** for suggestions which is copy field of content with different fieldType.

```
<field name="content" type="_textS"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="content_suggest" type="string"  indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="content_suggest"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Why would you use "copyField" instead of "DocValues" for this usecase?